# unity3d facebook 1.7 sdk no friends in device

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I've been stuck with this for a while. In editor I've got the friends id's with the following code, but on device the JSON is empty. Why is that, and how can I make it work on real enviroment?

```
FB.API ("/me?fields=friends{id,name}", HttpMethod.GET, delegate (IGraphResult result) {
            Debug.Log ("RawResult" + result.RawResult);
            if (result.RawResult != string.Empty) {
                List<object> rawJSON = Util.DeserializeJSONFriends (result.RawResult);
                foreach (object item in rawJSON) {      
                    friends = (Dictionary<string, object>)item; 
                    Debug.Log (friends ["id"]);
                }
            }
        });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With this updated code, it's good :)

```
    void AuthCallback (ILoginResult loginResult)
{
    if (loginResult.Error != null) {
        Util.LogError ("FREAK OUT WHILE LOGIN\n" + loginResult.Error); 
    } else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        Debug.LogWarning ("Canceled by the user");
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Login was succesfull");
        Debug.Log ("Players User id is: " + AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId);
        FB.API ("me?fields=id,name,email,friends.fields(first_name),first_name", HttpMethod.GET, GetFriendIDs);
    }
}

void GetFriendIDs (IGraphResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null) {
        Util.LogError ("\n\nFREAK OUT FROM JSON\n\n" + result.Error + "\n\n");
        FB.API ("me?fields=id,name,email,friends.fields(first_name),first_name", HttpMethod.GET, GetFriendIDs);
    } else if (result.RawResult != string.Empty) {
        List<object> rawJSON = Util.DeserializeJSONFriends (result.RawResult);
        foreach (object item in rawJSON) {      
            friends = (Dictionary<string, object>)item; 
            Debug.Log (friends ["id"]);
        }           
        Debug.Log ("RawResult" + result.RawResult);
    }               
    Application.LoadLevel ("Main");
}
```